# PrimeFaces inline edit <p:rowEditor /> overlaping tick icon with cross icon

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am using `primeface5.0`, Below code I used but `p:rowEditor's` both tick and cross icons are overlaping .

I am unable to update dataTable value, Please suggest me how to separate both icons of rowEditor.

```
<p:dataTable id="dataTable" var="vendor" value="#{vendorBean.vendorList}" editable="true" >

    <p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{vendorBean.onRowEdit}" />
        <p:ajax event="rowEditCancel" listener="#{vendorBean.onRowCancel}" />

   <p:column headerText="Name" style="width:150px">
       <p:cellEditor>
           <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{vendor.str_VendorName}" /></f:facet>
           <f:facet name="input"><p:inputText value="#{vendor.str_VendorName}" style="width:100%" label="Year"/></f:facet>
       </p:cellEditor>
   </p:column>

   <p:column headerText="Category" style="width:150px">
       <p:cellEditor>
           <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{vendor.str_VendorType}" /></f:facet>
           <f:facet name="input">
               <p:inputText value="#{vendor.str_VendorType}" style="width:100%"/>

           </f:facet>
       </p:cellEditor>
   </p:column>

   <p:column style="width:50px">
       <p:rowEditor />
   </p:column>

</p:dataTable>
```

Comment: I never seen this happening on PrimeFaces 5.0 or newer (or even older). Perhaps, some CSS of your own is playing this role. `style="width:50px"`, I suppose 50 pixel width is insufficient to hold/accommodate both the icons in the column that embeds `<p:rowEditor/>`. You may want to increase it sufficiently.

Comment: @Tiny thanks for ur reply.Sorry both the icons are showing but they r overlaping with each other m unable to distinguish tick icon at the time of posting dis question.so now can u tell me how to make separate both the icon m unable to do this bcoz they r the default icons of rowEditor.

Comment: They should be displayed properly. I see them being displayed properly in a column having a width of 50 pixel - `<p:column headerText="Edit" width="50">...</p:column>`. This may happen because of your own CSS/JS, If you happen to use somewhere which I am unaware of.

Comment: Try reproducing the problem on a blank playground JSF application having possibly a single XHTML file ignoring all other XHTML tags and/or CSS/JS mess, if any. (I am currently using PrimeFaces 5.1 but I had been using PrimeFaces 5.0 for a long time in the past where I never saw something like this). It is likely that something is being overlapped or you are probably using an old, obscure, buggy browser.

Comment: many many thanks for ur reply.@Tiny you are right That was  happened because of my  own CSS/JS.I just removed my  CSS/JS Now its perfectly displaying.thankssssssssssssss